# How calculate Conversion Rate by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want calculate Conversion Rate.

```
Conversion Rate = Total Number of Sales / Number of Leads * 100
```

I have `div` box with classes from which I want take these numbers. `.box-1 1 .total-number` and `.box-1 .leads-number`

```
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="total-number">400</div>
  <div class="leads-number">800</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you expect the result to display?

Comment: What javascript have you written so far?

Comment: What actually is your question? How to calculate CR? Or how to read the content of html tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.text()` method of jquery to get value of div and .text(value) to set text for div like this

```
function calculate(){
let totalNumber = $('.total-number').text();
let leadNumber = $('.leads-number').text();

let rate = (totalNumber) * 100 / leadNumber;

$('.conversion-rate').text(rate);
}
```

Update:

If you dont need click calculate button, move the code outside

```
let totalNumber = $('.total-number').text();
let leadNumber = $('.leads-number').text();

let rate = (totalNumber) * 100 / leadNumber;

$('.conversion-rate').text(rate);
```

```js
//function calculate(){
let totalNumber = $('.total-number').text();
let leadNumber = $('.leads-number').text();

let rate = (totalNumber) * 100 / leadNumber;

$('.conversion-rate').text(rate);
//}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="total-number">400</div>
  <div class="leads-number">800</div>
  
  <div class='conversion-rate'></div> 
  <!--<input type='button' value='Calculate' onclick='calculate()' />-->
</div>
```

Comment: how can display answer without click button

Comment: how make Round number final output (when i change numbers output gives  x.xxxxx)

Comment: You can use toFixed method like 1.233333.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

Get the text content from the two div using `innerHTML` and `trim` to remove white space.

```js
let totalNum = document.querySelector('.box-1').querySelector('.total-number').innerHTML.trim();
let leadNum = document.querySelector('.box-1').querySelector('.leads-number').innerHTML.trim();

let rate = (totalNum) * 100 / leadNum;

console.log(rate)
```

```html
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="total-number">400</div>
  <div class="leads-number">800</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
 const totalNumber = +document.querySelector('.total-number').textContent;
 const leadsNumber = +document.querySelector('.leads-number').textContent;
 const rate = totalNumber/leadsNumber*100;
 console.log(rate)
```

```html
 <div class="box-1">
  <div class="total-number">400</div>
  <div class="leads-number">800</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Dumping code with no detail is a poor way to answer.